# Is there any reason to search for Z values other than 1 when transforming X,Y to Jacobian representation of an EC Point?

Tags: elliptic-curves, schnorr-signature

When exchanging a public key I usually receive some compressed form of `X,Y` coordinates. To use some speed ups I'd need to represent that in the Jacobean `x,y,z` form.

`Z=1` satisfies everything and looking at the speed ups (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Jacobian_Coordinates, http://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-jacobian.html) I don't see an obvious reason why `Z=1` would be slower (or faster?) than any other `Z`, is this a legitimate question? Can you point me in some direction about "does it even make sense to look for `Z` other than 1?".

Comment: Isn't it clear? $Z^4$  that is 1 when $Z=1$ and for the other cases one need 3 doublings.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, when I do a multiplication of a point for a large number I'll do a bunch of additions, doubling, tripling, etc, and I was wondering if choosing a different z would have an impact. I'm not sure it makes sense as a question thought thanks again for the patience.

Comment: In scalar multiplication, a point is added, again and again (double-and-add), there is no fixed point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point doubling (Wiki link) requires `Z^4` and when used with the double-and-add algorithm (needed for public point calculation, ECDH, and EC-based signatures) using $Z=1$ simplifies the calculation of `Z^4` otherwise one may need 3 doublings. The double-and-add method where the `res` is not fixed to save time. Double-and-add Wikipedia [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add);

```
let bits = bit_representation(s) # the vector of bits (from MSB to LSB) representing s
let res = O # point at infinity
for bit in bits:
    res = res + res # double
    if bit == 1:            
        res = res + P # add
    i = i - 1
return res
```

This is the beginning of the long story. The ["m-fold double"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Jacobian_Coordinates#Repeated_Doubling_((4m-1)M_+_(4m+2)S)) (repeated doubling) calculates $[2^m]P$ and only calculates `Z^4` once. When you need $[k]P$, you may need to represent $k$ in the binary form then use m-fold doubling when necessary. To have benefited from this, one has to calculate the cost before deciding to use m-fold double or not.

The answer is not easy and complete, since [this one](http://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-jacobian.html#addition-zadd-2007-m) requires `Z1=Z2`   with `5M + 2S` for addition Wiki version has `12M + 4S` cost. The `5M + 2S` has still `Z1` multiplication and if `Z1=1` that has zero cost.

In a short sentence, in general, `Z1=1` simplifies the equations.

Since $(X_1:Y_1:Z_1)$ represents $(Z/Z^2,Y/Z^3)$ and $(X_1:Y_1:Z_1)$ is an equivalance relation that is $$(X_1:Y_1:Z_1) \sim (\lambda X_1:\lambda Y_1:\lambda Z_1)$$ one can simple convert the $Z_1 =1$ with $$(X_1/Z_1:Y_1/Z_1:1)$$

Keep in mind that `1/Z1` is not division, rather the inverse of `Z1` on the defining field.

The `Z1` on the other hand, is not staying there with `Z1=1` under the operations. To benefit from this, one has to find the inverse and execute two multiplication. Finding inverse, on the other hand, is what we don't want since it is costly.

So, at least there is a benefit at the beginning of scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: Far from a perfect answer, though....